# Перевод любого формата времени в минуты

Tags: java, datetime

На вход подается дата, которая может принимать различные форматы (HH:mm / HH / mm / S / s / D) и выдаёт результат в минутах. Как это реализовать? Желательно использовать Simpl Date Format или Java.Util.Date

Есть такая реализация, но она принимает только HH:mm

```
public void stepChangeDateFormat(String initialDate, String initialFormat, String finalFormat, String variable) {
        initialDate = evalVariable(initialDate);
        String dateHHMM = initialDate;
        String newDate;
        switch (initialFormat){
            case "Время":
                dateHHMM = (dateHHMM.charAt(initialDate.length() - 1) == 'ч') ? initialDate + "0м" : dateHHMM;
                dateHHMM = (dateHHMM.contains("ч") == false) ? "0ч " + initialDate : dateHHMM;
                dateHHMM = dateHHMM.replace(" ", "").replaceAll("ч", ":").replaceAll("[a-я]", "");
                dateHHMM = (dateHHMM.charAt(1) == ':') ? "0" + dateHHMM : dateHHMM;
                StringBuffer date = new StringBuffer(dateHHMM);
                date = (dateHHMM.length() == 4) ? date.insert(3, "0") : date;
                dateHHMM = date.toString();
                String[] timeParts = dateHHMM.split(":");
                newDate = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]));
                newDate = utilScenarioSteps.changeDateFormat(newDate,initialFormat, finalFormat);
                logger.info(String.format("Дата [%s] преобразована в [%s] и сохранена в переменную [%s]", initialDate, newDate, variable));
                utilScenarioSteps.setVariable(variable, newDate);
                break;
            default:
                newDate = utilScenarioSteps.changeDateFormat(initialDate, initialFormat, finalFormat);
                logger.info(String.format("Дата [%s] преобразована в [%s] и сохранена в переменную [%s]", initialDate, newDate, variable));
                utilScenarioSteps.setVariable(variable, newDate);
        }
```

Comment: Приведите примеры входных данных, пожалуйста

Comment: *Как это реализовать?* Собрать ВСЕ мыслимые форматы. Для каждого подготовить шаблон (код) преобразования (или убедиться, что подойдёт один из уже построенных). Построить дерево опознания формата по "сырым" данным (если он не задаётся вместе с входными данными). Ну и ... а всё, собственно.

Comment: @Chubatiy
HH:mm  (10:30 -> 630);
s (60 -> 1);
HH (5 -> 300)

Comment: @Akina, так не годится, нужно как-то приспособить к Simpl Date Format либо к Java.Util.Time

Comment: НУ так шаблон и есть собственно трансформация исходного кода в тот вид, который понимабелен для некоего стандартного формата или стандартного конвертора в такой формат. В показанном случае все три показанных формы приводятся к одной HH:mm:ss посредством добавления отсутствующих компонентов с нулевыми значениями, а затем запросто конвертируются в требуемые минуты.

Comment: Почему не привести все к миллисекундам и получить минуты?